# What is a more efficient way to tackle long "else if" statements in R?

Tags: r, loops, vectorization

I am looking for advice on how to improve efficiency of a long if/else loop in my r script. I am also looking to future-proof it as much as possible as the scope of it is likely to change over time.

#### Background

Using legacy code from another language, I am automating a reporting process for a large project. In this project I have multiple "Centers" to create reports for based on subsets of a database. Right now I accomplish this using a long sample loop like the one shown below:

```
df$ReportName <- 0

df$new_centername[is.na(df$new_centername)] <- 0

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if (df$new_centername[i] == 1){
    df$ReportName[i] <- "Center A"
  } else if (df$new_centername[i] == 2){
    df$ReportName[i] <- "Center B"
  } else if (df$new_centername[i] == 3){
    df$ReportName[i] <- "Center C"
  } else if (df$new_centername[i] == 4){
    df$ReportName[i] <- "Center D"
  } else if (df$new_centername[i] == 5){
    df$ReportName[i] <- "Center E"
  } else if (df$new_centername[i] == 6){
    df$ReportName[i] <- "Center F"
  } 
  ...
```

`df` is the general dataframe, `new_centername` designates which Center the row of data belongs to which are all coded numerically.

As time goes on I expect more Centers to be added to this. I assume there is a way to store these Centers in a list, then create a loop that iterates over the list. This way as new Centers are added I only have to add their name to the list.

#### Edit:

- "Center __" is only a placeholder to share here, the actual center names vary greatly.
- The numeric id also does not follow a straight linear pattern.

#### Proposed Solution:

```
SampleList <- list("Center A", "Center B", "Center C", ...)

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  for (j in 1:length(SampleList)){
    if (df$new_centername[i] == 1){
      df$ReportName[i] <- SampleList[j]
    }
  }
}
```

Help with wrapping my head around the best logic and appropriate syntax for optimization is greatly appreciated! **Thank you**

Comment: You can use `ifelse` which is vectorized and does not need loops

Comment: @Sotos Thank you for the feedback! I have used vectorized ifelse in the past, but since I have upwards of 60 unique identifiers this format would get equally confusing to weed through. That's why I'm looking for a more general solution that can map across a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code showed, we can do this directly assuming the values in 'new_centername' is a sequence starting from 1, it can be used as index for populating other values.  Below, we are creating a string vector with `paste0` such that 'Center A' would replace or get the position where 'new_centername' is 1, 'Center B', 2, and so on...  Just for showing the concept, have created only until 'Center F'.

```
df$new_centername <- paste0("Center ", LETTERS[1:6])[df$new_centername]
```

---

As the OP mentioned about no pattern in replacement values and the index is also different, then the effective approach (also suggested in the comments by @JasonAizkalns) would be to create a key/val dataset and then join with the original data

```
keyval <- data.frame(key = c(5, 12, 13, 25), 
                     val = c('ASD', 'BDF', 'ANF', 'SDT'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[keyval, new_name := val, on = .(new_center_name = key)]
df
```

Comment: Nice approach, maybe to "future proof", create a large list/vector/DB, and then a left join? Or adjust LETTERS[i] to be consistent with the length of the incoming?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns  Thanks.  As long as the values in the vector length is equal to the length of unique index, it should work.  I am assuming that the OP already have a vector of 'Center '  values length that matches the original index

Comment: Hi @akrun, this is a great solution for sequential names and numerics. For my problem "Center __" is only a placeholder for actual center names to protect their identities. The actual names vary greatly with no patterns and the numerics have some sight variations. That's why I'm hoping I can map across the `SampleList`. I'll update the post to reflect this.

Comment: Or, slightly simpler: `paste0("Center ", LETTERS[df$new_centername])`

Comment: @rsh52  You can create a vector of names (this one was only a demonstration based on the pattern), and if the numerics also vary, then I would suggest to create a key/val data.frame and do a left_join, but there is stilll a pain in creating the key/val dataset as there is no pattern.  In the end, it would be much better and efficient than writing nested `ifelse` (BTW, there is a limit for `ifelse`, - perhaps around 54 or so)